# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"members", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth

I set up twitter login system and got the error message above around the codes

```
 redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]), :notice => "#{auth["info"]["name"]}さんの#{auth["provider"]}アカウントと接続しました。"
```

in the def callback of the sessions_controller.rb. I wonder why this happened because it never happened when I set up facebook login with omniauth gem.Could you tell me why this occurred and how to solve this?

I checked some elements. A new user was created through twitter login. And I could get "session". But couldn't acquire session[:user_id].

☆member.rb

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |member|
      member.provider = auth["provider"]
      member.uid = auth["uid"]
      member.mail = auth["mail"]
      member.image = auth["info"]["image"]

      if member.provider == "facebook"
        member.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      else
        member.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
      end
    end
  end
```

☆sessions_controller

```
 def callback
    #omniauth.auth環境変数を取得
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    #Userモデルを検索
    member = Member.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])

    if member
       # 既存のユーザ情報があった場合ルートに遷移させます
       session[:user_id] = member.id
       redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]), :notice => "ログインしました。"
    else
       # Userモデルに:providerと:uidが無い場合（外部認証していない）、保存してからルートへ遷移させる
       Member.create_with_omniauth(auth)
       redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]), :notice => "#{auth["info"]["name"]}さんの#{auth["provider"]}アカウントと接続しました。"
    end
  end
```

Comment: do you use any gem for authentication?

Comment: I am using omuniauth gem. Thank you. gem 'omniauth' gem 'omniauth-facebook' 'omniauth-twitter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to build a member route which requires `id` for member. Other words Rails should build routes like `/members/:id` where id MUST be a number. When you pass `session[:id]` (which is nil!) to the route helper `member_path` you get an error.

What to do?

1) (if you use a gem for authentication, for example `devise`) you can pass to the route helper `current_user`: `memeber_path(current_user)`

2) if you have own method which authenticate user you can set `session[:user_id]` youself.
I suppose that the problem is in else-block. So you can define session[`user_id`] after a new Member is created. I hope that method `Member.create_with_omniauth(auth)` return a new member - it means that you need take its id

```
if member
   # 既存のユーザ情報があった場合ルートに遷移させます
   session[:user_id] = member.id
   redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]), :notice => "ログインしました。"
else
   # Userモデルに:providerと:uidが無い場合（外部認証していない）、保存してからルートへ遷移させる
   session[:user_id] = Member.create_with_omniauth(auth).id # <--- UPDATED PART IS HERE      
   redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]), :notice => "#{auth["info"]["name"]}さんの#{auth["provider"]}アカウントと接続しました。"
end
```

PS
And anyway you can avoid to render/redirect to this route if `session[:user_id]` is nil

```
redirect_to member_path(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Could you tell me how to set session[:user_id] by myself in this setting??

Comment: Mr.gotva, thank you very very much!! Thanks to you, I made it!!